# Updating intermediary tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 questions regarding how to create and update my intermediary table. For example, I have two tables, students and subject modules with many-to-many relationship and they look like this:

```
student                             class
student_id student_name             class_id class_name
1          John                     1        Economics
2          Mary                     2        Physics
```

The intermediary table will be as follow, where John takes only Physics class while Mary takes both Physics and Economics classes:

```
studentclasses
id student_id class_id
1  1          2
2  2          1
3  2          2
```

**My first question is this:** Since the student and class tables are small, I can manually create the intermediary table. As I work with larger data sets, how can I create my intermediary table?

**My second question:** If i would to receive a new entry with all the information, ie. `student_name, student_class`, how do I then update this new entry into my intermediary table?

PS. I am using Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
insert into studentclasses (student_id, class_id)
    select s.student_id, c.class_id
    from (values ('John', 'Physics'),
                 ('Mary', 'Economics'),
                 ('Mary', 'Physics')
         ) v(student_name, class_name) join
         student s
         on s.student_name = v.student_name join
         class c
         on c.class_name = v.class_id;
```

That is, you have a source of student name/class name pairs.  In this query, that is provided by a `values()` statement.  Then you can `join` to the appropriate tables to get the ids that you want.

Of course, if you know the ids to begin with, you do not need to join.  You can just insert directly into the table.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I want. Just to clarify since I just started learning sql, I can just replace the values() statement with a table with all the pairings right?

Comment: @JasonTay . . . Yes, you can do that.